# input axis mouse scrollwheel is not setup

Tags: unity3d, input

Я использую Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") в своем коде для юнити, однако он попросту не работает, а юнити говорит что input axis mouse scrollwheel is not setup, и что нужно его менять в настройках. Я туда зашел, а что менять - не понял. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Edit → Project Settings → Input Manager → развернуть Axes посмотреть есть ли пункт `Mouse ScrollWheel` если есть, но с другим названием то можно поменять либо тут, либо в коде.

Comment: Проблема вообще сама собой пропала. Бред..